# Inserting data into a table from a Dynamic SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, insert, cursor, dynamic-sql

I am trying to run this script:

```
DECLARE @Client VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DBReporting VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @DBSignet VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @databasename varchar(100)

    SET @SQL = ''

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  name 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE name like '%reporting%' 
           AND NOT Name Like '%UAT%'
           AND NOT Name Like '%Test%'
           AND NOT Name Like '%Demo%'
           AND NOT Name like '%staging%'
           AND NOT Name like '%server%'
           AND state_desc <> 'offline'

    OPEN db_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @databasename

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @Client = REPLACE(REPLACE(@databasename, 'SourcingPlatform_', ''), '_Reporting', '')

        SET @DBSignet = 'SourcingPlatform_' + @Client + '_Signet_Tradeflow'
        SET @DBReporting = 'SourcingPlatform_' + @Client + '_Reporting'

        SET @SQL = @SQL + 'INSERT INTO STS_Branding.[dbo].[S2C_KeyStats]
           ([Project]
           ,[DataDate]
           ,[EventTypeName]
           ,[CountOfAllEvents]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast3Months]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast6Months]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast12Months])
     VALUES

        SELECT ''' + @Client + ''' AS Client, convert(date, getdate()), EventTypeName collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
        count(id) as CountOfAllEvents,

        (select COUNT(e3.ID) 
        from    ' + @DBReporting + '..REPORTS_Sourcing_Event E3
        where   DATEDIFF(month,CreateDate, GETDATE()) <= 3
        and     E.EventTypeName = E3.EventTypeName) as CreatedLast3Months,

        (select COUNT(e6.ID) 
        from    ' + @DBReporting + '..REPORTS_Sourcing_Event E6
        where   DATEDIFF(month,CreateDate, GETDATE()) > 3
        and     DATEDIFF(month,CreateDate, GETDATE()) <= 6
        and     E.EventTypeName = E6.EventTypeName) as CreatedLast6Months,

        (select COUNT(e12.ID) 
        from    ' + @DBReporting + '..REPORTS_Sourcing_Event E12
        where   DATEDIFF(month,CreateDate, GETDATE()) > 6
        and     DATEDIFF(month,CreateDate, GETDATE()) <= 12
        and     E.EventTypeName = E12.EventTypeName) as CreatedLast12Months,

        (select COUNT(e13.ID) 
        from    ' + @DBReporting + '..REPORTS_Sourcing_Event E13
        where   DATEDIFF(month,CreateDate, GETDATE()) > 12
        and     E.EventTypeName = E13.EventTypeName) as CreatedOver12Months

        FROM ' + @DBReporting + '..REPORTS_Sourcing_Event E

        Group By EventTypeName

        UNION '

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @databasename
    END

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SET @sql =  substring(@sql, 0, LEN(@sql) - len('UNION ')) + ' ORDER BY Client, EventTypeName collate Latin1_General_CI_AS'

--PRINT @SQL
exec(@SQL)
```

However, I am getting a syntax error.

I have printed the @SQL variable and the code generated looks good to me. Am I missing something really simple here? or am I way off what I want to achieve?

What I want to achieve is a script that goes through each DB referenced in the first select and get the values and insert them into my table.

Let me know if you need anymore information to help me, any help at all at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?  What is inside `@SQL` at the point of execution?

Comment: The error I got originally was because I had put values and then using select straight after. I removed the values and I was then faced with the issue Honey Badger pointed out to me. I am now getting an incorrect syntax near the word from. I will update my question to reflect this now. Many thanks, Dave

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the generated query, but I think it looks something like:

```
INSERT INTO STS_Branding.[dbo].[S2C_KeyStats]
           ([Project]
           ,[DataDate]
           ,[EventTypeName]
           ,[CountOfAllEvents]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast3Months]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast6Months]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast12Months])
VALUES -- Remove this, it's incorrect in combination with SELECT     
SELECT   (lots of selects)

UNION

INSERT INTO STS_Branding.[dbo].[S2C_KeyStats]
           ([Project]
           ,[DataDate]
           ,[EventTypeName]
           ,[CountOfAllEvents]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast3Months]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast6Months]
           ,[CreatedWithinLast12Months])

SELECT   (lots of selects)
```

This is obviously not possible, you want to `union` the `selects` not the `insert`. So you should begin by initialling `@SQL` with the `insert` statement (outside the cursor). Inside the cursor you can use `SET @SQL = @SQL + ...` as you are already doing, but without the `insert` statement.

Also, please note `substring` is `1` based in SQL, not `0` as in, for example, C#.

Comment: Thanks HoneyBadger. This helped me a lot. I got another error after this which is inregards to a syntax error. I left a comma in between the last column and the FROM clause. This answer helped me and solved the issue thanks.

Comment: @Dave, please see edit: I removed `VALUES`, it is incorrect to use in an `insert` with `select`. I think that was your error.

Comment: yes I had removed this as soon as I seen had I had put it in. Thanks a lot for your help. Greatly Appreciated.